# Sorting an array / table in JavaScript with keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a simple list and I am trying to create a search filter for this, you enter a keyword and it goes through the function and re-sorts this data list to show only ones that apply to the keyword

```js
list: [
  {name: "Apple"},
  {name: "Grape"}
]
```

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly. It is not so clear what exactly do you want?

Comment: Not sure what sorting has to do with keywords. Array filter?

Comment: This is called 'filtering', not 'sorting'. You may, of course, also be planning to sort the filtered results, I don't know. Please include an example of some input and what the desired results would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ili is right, [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the good way but it would be much better with a [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) too, because the current answer can only works if the person type exactly the good word. Here is an implementation more user-friendly :

```js
list = [
  {name: "Apple"},
  {name: "Grape"}
]

input = "app"

filtered = list.filter(element => {
    if(element.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
        return element
    }
})

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var list = [
  {name: "Apple"},
  {name: "Grape"}
];
var filtered = list.filter(function(o){
  return o.name == "Apple";
});
```